# nodejs asynchronously reading continuously growing file

Tags: node.js, fs, file-read

I am trying to read a text file which is continuously growing (adding new lines at end) with very high rate, lets say ~100 lines per seconds where line size is approximate 200 characters.

I tried following , which is working but lagging by a minute and so.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = "D:\\testreadwrite.txt";

fs.watchFile(path, function() {
    console.log('File Changed ...');
    file = fs.readFileSync(path);
    console.log('File content at : ' + new Date() + ' is \n' + file);
    });
```

I really do not need synchronous reading but lagging > 1 minute is too high, and i do need entire file each time. All i need is , read the data and process line by line, for each new line coming. so i tried below code where i am planning to loop through and pass offset for each iteration. But this code is not working for some unknown reasons. Please help.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = "D:\\Work\\Jai Ho\\myapp\\public\\testreadwrite.txt";
fs.watch(path, function(event, filename) {
  if(filename){
            fs.stat(path, function(error, stats) {
              fs.open(path, "r", function(error, fd) {
               var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
                fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
                  var data = buffer.toString("utf8");
                  console.log(data);
                });
              });
            });

  }
  else{
    console.log('filename not provided')
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you get when you return or log `err`? also what do you get when you log `filename` , `stats` and `error` in `stat()` function, this will help us understand where the error is coming from better @sand

Comment: I added if(error){ console.log(error);} in stat() function but that doesn't show anything.

Comment: you can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/tail module. Hope will help you. Implementation example you can see here https://github.com/shubhambatra/read-log/blob/master/server.js

Comment: I tried  but there is some problem with npm install -tail - save. It gives errors. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})